# Playwright page.pdf() only gets one page

Tags: python, pdf, playwright, playwright-python

I have been trying to convert html to pdf. I have tried a lot of tools but none of them work. Now I am using playwright, it is converting the Page to PDF but it only gets the first screen view. From that page the content from right is trimmed.

```
import os
import time
import pathlib
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

filePath = os.path.abspath("Lab6.html")
fileUrl = pathlib.Path(filePath).as_uri()
fileUrl = "file://C:/Users/PMYLS/Desktop/Code/ScribdPDF/Lab6.html"
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(fileUrl)
    for i in range(5): #(The scroll is not working)
        page.mouse.wheel(0, 15000)
        time.sleep(2)
    page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle') 
    page.emulate_media(media="screen")
    page.pdf(path="sales_report.pdf")
    browser.close()
```

Html View

[image: Html view]

PDF file after running script
[image: pdf view]
I have tried almost every tool available on the internet. I also used selenium but same results. I thought it was due to page not loaded properly, I added wait and manually scrolled the whole page to load the content. All giving same results.

The html I am converting
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16jEq52iXtAMCg2FDt3VbQN0dCQmdTip_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ggorlen I apologize, I thought I had added it. you can view it now

Comment: Thanks, the problem is likely due to the fact that it's in a little scrolling window wrapper. Do you need that to be in the output PDF? If so, what would that look like, exactly? It wouldn't match the normal page. I would remove the `class="document_scroller"` and the screenshot on the interior content should work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a somewhat dirty solution that worked on my end. The `sleep` and scroll isn't great and can probably be improved, but I'll leave this as a starter and see if I have time to tighten it up later (feel free to do the same).

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.37.0
from time import sleep


with open("index.html") as f:
    html = f.read()

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)

    # focus inside the annoying border to enable scroll
    page.click(".document_container")

    for i in range(10):
        page.mouse.wheel(0, 2500)
        sleep(0.5)

    # strip out the annoying border that messes up PDF generation
    page.evaluate("""() => {
        const el = document.querySelector(".document_scroller");
        el.parentElement.appendChild(el.querySelector(".document_container"));
        el.remove();
    }""")
    page.emulate_media(media="screen")
    page.pdf(path="sales_report.pdf")
    browser.close()
```

Two tricks:

1. Clicking inside the border area enables scrolling, which appears necessary to get everything to load.
2. Ripping out the annoying border allows the PDF generation to capture all pages. When the border is present, there's no scroll on the main body, only on the interior container, which the PDF capture doesn't seem to understand.

Comment: Just a question, What if I remove the outere containers of document. Will it skip all the other steps? Like scrolling and sleep

Comment: Like I have millions of html files being downloaded, If I can alter it to fix this before writing those htmls

Comment: Also, there are many images not loaded in pdf, I would have wait for the images to load first, right?

Comment: I didn't have time to play with it (I'll update when I do), but please experiment and see if you can get rid of the sleeps and scroll, or speed them up. I found that removing the scroll caused images to fail to load, but there may be a solution to that problem, maybe stripping the wrapper and waiting for network idle. This is just a "first effort" answer to get you moving again and give you something to build from, not necessarily the best approach. The images all seem in there in this solution, though, so it should be correct, albeit slow.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I am working on it. You saved a lot of time xD

Comment: You might be able to collect all the image srcs, then render and load them offscreen quickly, avoiding the scroll. Dunno... feel free to add an answer if you make any progress and improve on this.